# How to display context actions in dropdown menues ?

Tags: contextual-menu

I having little difficulties to display a context menu for dropdown menu actions:

[image]

The picture shows the problem quite by-self: whilst the click on 'Google' does still its job, its pretty confusing as the context menu shows up.

My only idea to fix this is showing 'Edit' and 'Remove' delayed in more 'separated' popup box. I am not still not sure this is the way to go, is it ?

well, thank you, any ideas are welcome.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can display Action icons on hover of an option inside menu. The menu can be a bit wider than this one.

Another option can be to display the two icons at the bottom of menu, separated from menu options by a separator. Add check boxes along with options. First select an option and then click on Edit/Remove icon.

Comment: awesome, i take it, never came to my mind! thank you!